# Как выбрать число, стоящее в начале строки, либо после пробельного символа?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо регулярным выражением найти число.
По заданию система должна найти либо первый символ в строке, который является числом (например `3Яблоко` - должно выбрать `3`), либо первый числовой символ перед которым идут пробелы.

Мучаюсь уже несколько дней.
Начало строки `^` - понятно, пробельные символы `\s` - понятно, но вместе через `[^|\s]` - не работает. `\b` - не получается использовать, так как он ловит `.`, а по заданию `.3яблока 4 _5` должно выбрать `4`, т.е. точка `.` для меня существенный знак (и запятая тоже). Если число идет после точки или запятой, то выбирать эти числа нельзя!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

такое выражение ищет цифру, которая следует за началом строки или пробелом

```
(?:^|\s)(\d)
```

если надо не цифру, а число

```
(?:^|\s)(\d+)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, по конструкции ?: описаний очень мало   - "группировка как и '( )', но без обратной ссылки" - все что нашел, но все работает как надо. Рейтинга пока не хватает, чтобы поставить вам баллы :)

Comment: @Dennis  1) если вы ставите ?: после скобки, то то, что  в скобках, не будет попадать а результаты поиска, например, в массив (3й аргумент) preg_match. 2) вы можете нажать галочку слева от ответа, "приняв" таким образом ответ, раз он кажется вам правильным и полезным